# How to avoid "access denied" warnings in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am using phpMyAdmin on grendalhosting. I keep on getting these errors no matter what I do. I am new to PHP/MySQL.

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.1.2.21'
>   (using password: NO) in /home/u438954871/public_html/url
>   shortner/connect.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) in /home/u438954871/public_html/url
>   shortner/connect.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be
>   established in /home/u438954871/public_html/url shortner/connect.php
>   on line 9
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) in /home/u438954871/public_html/url
>   shortner/shorten.php on line 28
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established
>   in /home/u438954871/public_html/url shortner/shorten.php on line 28
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in /home/u438954871/public_html/url shortner/shorten.php on line
>   29
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) in /home/u438954871/public_html/url
>   shortner/shorten.php on line 34
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established
>   in /home/u438954871/public_html/url shortner/shorten.php on line 34
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) in /home/u438954871/public_html/url
>   shortner/shorten.php on line 35
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established
>   in /home/u438954871/public_html/url shortner/shorten.php on line 35
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in /home/u438954871/public_html/url shortner/shorten.php on line
>   36 Your info was not added. Warning: mysql_close(): no MySQL-Link
>   resource supplied in /home/u438954871/public_html/url
>   shortner/shorten.php on line 45

Php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>URL shortner</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css">
<body>

<?php 
    if ($_POST['shortbtn']){
        $url = $_POST['url'];

        if ($url) {

            require ("./connect.php");

            $charset = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            $len = 5;
            $numrows = 1;

            while ($numrows != 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $len; $i++){
                    $rand = rand () % strlen($charset);
                    $tmp = $substr($charset, $rand, 1);
                    $code .= $tmp;
            }

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE code='$code'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        }

        $data = date("F d, Y"); // July 8, 2015

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO urls VALUES ('', '$url', '$code', '$date')");
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE code='$code'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($numrows == 1) {
            $site = "shrty";
            echo "Your shortened url: <input type='text' size='40' value='$site/$code'>";
        }
        else
            echo "Your info was not added.";

            mysql_close();
        }

        else
            echo "<script type="text/javascript">window.location = './index.html'</script>";
    }
    else
        echo "<script type="text/javascript">window.location = './index.html'</script>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

load.php:

```
<?php

$code = $_GET['code'];

require("./connect.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE code='$code'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows == 1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $url = $row['url'];

    header("Location: $url");

    echo "<script text="text/javascript">window.location = '$url'</script>";
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

connect.php:

```
<?php

$server = "mysql.grendalhosting.com";
$db_user = "username";
$db_pass = "password";
$db_table = "urls";

mysql_connect ($server, $db_user);
mysql_select_db($db_table);

?>
```

PS: I don't have WAMP installed.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed very soon in PHP. Use mysqli_* instead. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use mysql_connect because this function is deprecated. You could use mysqli instead.

According your error, your root user doesn't have password. You should put "" as its value

Comment: where do I exactly put the value? inside $db_pass? and I changed mysqli like you said and got "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'u438954871_url'@'10.1.2.21' (using password: NO) in /home/u438954871/public_html/url shortner/connect.php on line 8". Sorry for the trouble

Comment: According to your post, you should put  `$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't passed the third parameter i.e. password parameter to `mysql_connect()` function. If your mysql server doesn't have password, the pass as blank ("") to `mysql_connect()` function.
As I'm saying, your code should be as below.

```
$server="mysql.grendalhosting.com";
$db_user="username";
$db_pass="password";//If no password, then keep it as blank ("")
mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

Then your database selection code as in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to pass password parameter in connect method.